# DPA Attack on HMAC SHA-256

Tags: hmac, sha-256, side-channel-attack, dpa

I have read the paper [Differential Power Analysis of HMAC SHA-2
in the Hamming Weight Model](http://www.di.ens.fr/~belaid/articleHMAC.pdf) and I want to understand the DPA Attack. In section 3.2.1 Path 1 (page 4) there is written:

> The  last  remaining parts H$^{(0)}$ and C$^{(0)}$ can be recovered by making substitutions in Alg. 1:  in Step 7 of round 1, where
>   H$^{(0)}$ is the only unknown variable, and similarly in Step 8 of round 1 where C$^{(0)}$ is the only unknown variable.

The substitution for $H^{(0)}$ is clear to me:

- $T_1^{(1)} = \delta^{(0)} \boxplus W_1$ (1)
- $T_1^{(1)} = H^{(0)} \boxplus \sum_1(E^{(0)}) \boxplus Ch(E^{(0)},F^{(0)},G^{(0)}) \boxplus K_1 \boxplus W_1$ (2)
- (1) = (2):
- $\delta^{(0)} \boxplus W_1 = H^{(0)} \boxplus \sum_1(E_0) \boxplus Ch(E^{(0)},F^{(0)},G^{(0)}) \boxplus K_1 \boxplus W_1$
- $\delta^{(0)} = H^{(0)} \boxplus \sum_1(E^{(0)}) \boxplus Ch(E^{(0)},F^{(0)},G^{(0)}) \boxplus K_1$
- $H^{(0)} = \delta^{(0)} \boxminus \sum_1(E^{(0)}) \boxminus Ch(E^{(0)},F^{(0)},G^{(0)}) \boxminus K_1$

But for $C^{(0)}$ I don't know how to start and my other problem is that I don't know how to substitute in the function `Maj`?

Answer (score 1):

I will keep the same notations as in the paper mentioned above.

First, your substitution for $H^{(0)}$ is correct but you could stop to
\begin{align*}
T_1^{(1)} = H^{(0)}\boxplus \Sigma_1(E^{(0)}) \boxplus Ch(E^{(0)}, F^{(0)}, G^{(0)}) \boxplus K_1 \boxplus W_1
\end{align*}
since all values except $H^{(0)}$ are known from previous DPAs.

Regarding $C^{(0)}$, it is a little less straightforward. We have
\begin{align*}
T_2^{(1)} &= \Sigma_0(A^{(0)}) \boxplus Maj(A^{(0)}, B^{(0)}, C^{(0)})\\
&= \Sigma_0(A^{(0)}) \boxplus \big[(A^{(0)} \wedge B^{(0)}) \oplus (A^{(0)} \wedge C^{(0)}) \oplus(B^{(0)} \wedge C^{(0)})\big]
\end{align*}
which results in
\begin{align*}
\big[T_2^{(1)} \boxminus \Sigma_0(A^{(0)})\big] \oplus (A^{(0)} \wedge B^{(0)})&=  (A^{(0)} \wedge C^{(0)}) \oplus(B^{(0)} \wedge C^{(0)}) \,.
\end{align*}
Unfortunately, as bitwise AND operator is not invertible, we don't get $C^{(0)}$ directly. Still, $C^{(0)}$ is the only unknown variable making a bruteforce attack on this 32-bit variable easy in practice.